# Can't refresh migration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I delete a migration file manually. Now I try to run the migrations with:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

I get an error:

```
  [ErrorException]                                                             
  include(C:\xampp\htdocs\NightClubs/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_cr  
  eate_users_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

This is the name of the migration file that I deleted. What to do?

Comment: Did you delete the record in your database as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema for migrations records the names of the files run through the `artisan migrate` command.

[image: Laravel Migration Schema in MySQL Database]

If you experience errors after deleting a migration class file, simply delete the record from the `migrations` table. If you have the liberty, completely dismantle the database and start from scratch.

Comment: Yes this helps. We can also use composer dump-autoload.